# On the horizontal behaviour of certain complex functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\{z=x+iy:\ 0\leq x\leq 1,\ t>2\}$ and it satisfies $|f(x +it)| = O(t^{(1-x)/2}\log t)$ for $0 \le x \le1$. In particular, $|f(it)| = O(t^{1/2}\log t)$. Is it true that $|f(x +it)| \le |f(it)|$ for $t$ sufficiently large and all $0\leq x\leq 1$?

Your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: The MO website is for questions of mathematical research. Is there a research angle to your question?

Comment: Yes: to show that for the Riemann Zeta function in the critical strip: modulus[zeta(x+it) <= modulus[Zeta(it)]. It seems that there is no proof of this relation in the literature, although the relation can be proved for x = 1. Maybe this relation can be directly proved. I believe it will complement the behavior of the Zeta function in the critical strip, thus the research angle to the question. I researched, asked a lot of people and tried to prove it, but I found no proof so far. This inequality is supported by numerical results.

Comment: Numerical/graphical support can be found in: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136881/MathSlov_53-2003-2_3.pdf   page 150

Comment: OK. I have formatted the question in TeX. I hope I haven't introduced any mistakes. Please edit into the body of your question the explanation of the Zeta motivation – people shouldn't have to go to the comments to see where a question is coming from. And please do it using TeX.

Comment: I edited your question to avoid easy conterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment below the original post, you are mainly interested in the case of $f(s)=\zeta(s)$. Let me restrict to that case.

Then, for a given $t$, your inequality is implied by Conjecture 1 in *Filip Saidak and Peter Zvengrowski*, [On the modulus of the Riemann zeta function in the critical strip](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136881/MathSlov_53-2003-2_3.pdf), *Math. Slovaca* **53** (2003), no. 2, 145-172 ([MR1986257](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1986257)), using the main result of this paper. Note that this conjecture is stated for $t\geq 2\pi +1$, and in fact it fails for $t$ small.
For example, $|\zeta(0)|<1<|\zeta(0.5)|$ and $|\zeta(6i)|<0.9<|\zeta(0.5+6i)|$.

Comment: For the Big O equality, t should be > 0, and probably 2*pi +1 as mentioned the link above.

Comment: @HassSaidane: Well, then you should state your question that way. Note also that without any analycity assumption, your function can be pretty arbitrary.

Comment: t should be > 0

Comment: @HassSaidane: The inequality fails for $f(s)=\zeta(s)$ and $t=6$. See my updated response. Also, it is not clear what you mean by "Big O equality". Your question is about monotonicity, it has nothing to do with "Big O".

Comment: As mentioned in the link above, without using the big O relation, I believe t should be > 2*pi+ 1

Comment: @HassSaidane: Yes, but your question makes no assumption on $t$. Note that for $f(s)=\zeta(s/100)$, say, you need to make $t>600$. So please try to ask the question as you mean it, because as things stand I answered it in the negative.

Comment: You are right, which is true for the Riemann zeta function. The big O says that the modulus is of the order of...

Comment: @HassSaidane: Well, $\zeta(s)$ satisfies the order conditions, at least for $t>2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36439/discussion-between-hass-saidane-and-gh-from-mo).

Comment: I did some experiments graphing modulus[Zeta(x+ it)] as a function of x, in the critical strip. The inequality of interest is true for t >= 6.825. So the condition on t >= 2*pi + 1 is good since it's analytically based. It's not clear how to go from the result in the referred to paper to the inequality. Could you elaborate and show how. Thanks

Comment: @HassSaidane: The authors mention that their condition $t\geq 2\pi +1$ can be improved, e.g. to $t>7$. So it is not analytically based, it was just convenient for them in certain steps of their proof.

Comment: Yes, the analytical result is better. Thanks. Now the question is, how can the inequality of interest be deduced from their inequality?

Comment: @HassSaidane: Their Theorem 1 implies that $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\zeta(x+it)|=\max_{0\leq x\leq 1/2}|\zeta(x+it)|$, and their Conjecture 1 implies that $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1/2}|\zeta(x+it)|=|\zeta(it)|$. Putting these two statements together, $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\zeta(x+it)|=|\zeta(it)|$, and this is what you asked. I assume $t\geq 2\pi+1$ of course.

Comment: Thanks GH: Conjecture 1 is just a conjecture, the authors introduced , but not proved. They state that if it can be proved, it would prove the Riemann Hypothesis true.  So the inequality of interest still needs a proof.

Comment: @HassSaidane: I agree. Your conjecture specialized to $f(s)=\zeta(s)$ is weaker than Conjecture 1, and it would be interesting to prove this weaker conjecture. Personally, I think that this is quite hard, perhaps as hard as Conjecture 1 (that implies the Riemann Hypothesis). Let's hope that I am wrong.